# Define histogram ranges

Tags: r

I want to create an histogram  with three bins: [0,1[,[1,2[,>=2. How can I specify this type of ranges? The only way I know to do this is with seq, but with that I do not know how can I specify the las bin.

Comment: you can use `cut` to cut, `table` to tabulate, and `barplot` to plot. see `?cut` ,  `?table`  and `?barplot` .

Comment: can you show how do you use these three functions to solve my problem?

Comment: @costa_25 if you want people to actually show you how to use, you should provide a minimal reproducible example to play with, and post the code you managed to have so far

Comment: you need to make and effort and try something out and if it doesn't work then try to figure out why and if it still doesn't work then I'm sure that everyone here will be glad to help you out. :-)

Comment: a<- c(1,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,4,3,2,5,7,1)

Comment: another idea: use the `breaks` argument in `hist`  (see `?hist`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the manual pages for `cut()` and `barplot()`:

```
vals <- cut(a, breaks=c(0, 1, 2, max(a)), right=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE)
table(vals)
# vals
# [0,1) [1,2) [2,7] 
#     4     4     9 
barplot(table(vals))
```

Where [ means the value is included and ) means it is excluded. The space=0 argument will close the space between the bars making it look a bit more histogram-like. If you want a true histogram:

```
hist(a, breaks=c(0, 1, 2, max(a)), right=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

But you will get density values where the area, not the height indicates the number of values in the bar.